# Iphone 5 and 5s - select from photo library - fine on every device except Iphone 5

Tags: ios, iphone

This is a very strange problem that only occurs on the iPhone 5 in my app

I have a 'change image' action which does not work at all on 5 but is fine on 5s , 6 , 6+ etc.

On the iPhone 5 and 4s when you try to action the command from a button it doesn't select the photo library in fact when you go to settings , privacy , photos it doesn't list the app there.
Works perfect on 5s , 6 , 6+ , and iOS is uptodate

I don't know of any differences with Xcode and 5 to 5s so i am stumped as to why this is happening
Code is fine and IOS is up to date

```
- (IBAction)changeimage:(id)sender {


NSLog(@"changing %@",imagenamelabel.text);


if (imagenamelabel.text == [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Profile"]) {
      NSLog(@"available ");
    imagepicked = 1;
    {
        NSLog(@"available2 ");


        if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            [self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil];

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: It doesn't work on iPhone 5 or iPod touch 5th gen

Comment: Explains doesn't work. iOS version ? Does your code pass the if tests? Which ones? Did you authorize your app to access photo ?

Comment: It works fine on 5s , 6 , 6+ it selects the photo library then imports the photo ( code not listed )...on the iPhone 5 it doesn't even select the photo library and doesn't even get listed in the Settings , privacy , Photos section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[imagenamelabel.text isEqualToString:@"Profile"]` for your string comparisons.  `==` is not a valid way to compare `NSString`.  It happens to work on 5s, 6, and 6+ because they are 64-bit devices that use tagged pointers for `NSString` but that isn't behavior that can be relied on.